# What is the best Classification Method alternative to Nominal Logistic Regression, if your Response and all Predictor variables are Categorical?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, logistic-regression

Hy, I need help in choosing the best classification method. My response variable is nominal with "4" categories and five predictor variables, two of them are nominal and three are binary. Kindly explain to me which method I should go with as I try using Multinomial logistics regression from R library "nnet" and I am not getting satisfying results.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed your categorical features into some continuous space, and then perform any classification method on the embedding. For example, use spectral encoding ([link 1](https://towardsdatascience.com/spectral-encoding-of-categorical-features-b4faebdf4a)) or other types of encodings ([link 2](https://medium.com/data-design/visiting-categorical-features-and-encoding-in-decision-trees-53400fa65931)).

You can use techniques from language modelling, for example this paper ([link 3](https://aclanthology.org/N13-1090/)) where it is shown how to learn numeric representations of words (which are nominal things).

Logistic regression might still show poor results if the embedded data are not linearly separated. In that case, try non-linear methods such as decision trees, support vector machines, $k$ nearest neighbors,  random forest, etc.

Alternatively, try to write an algorithm that learns the rules that separate your data into classes such as

```
if var1 == value1 and var2 == value2 and var3 == 0 and var4 == 1 and var 5 == 0 then class1
```

If your nominal variables don't have too many values, the rules can be learned fast.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation :)

Comment: @Usama2298 The comments section is not the right place for saying 'thanks'. Please read  [the rules of Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/tour) in order to make the experience with this site pleasant for you and for those who interact with you.